# PHP Substring of Regular Expression match,and regular expression not always working

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create an html parser like BBCode.
For example I want to parse items from html text with the following format:
`.....html..... [I]Item1[/I].....html....[I]Item2[/I]......`
So I am using a regular expression to get the `[I]XXXXX[/I]` I also want the regex to return only the Item1 to avoid `str_replace`. At the moment I am using `str_replace [I]` with `""` and `[/I]` with `""` to get the Item1. The problem is that the regular expression is not always working.
I am using the code bellow:

```
$pattern="/\[I]([^\[].)+\[\/I]/m";
preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$out,PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($out as $i)
{
    $temp=$i[0];
    echo "Found!";
    $i[0]=str_replace("[I]","",$i[0]);
    $i[0]=str_replace("[/I]","",$i[0]);
    ......
}
```

My regular expression means: Starts with `[I]` continues with any character except `[` (To avoid `[I] [I] [/I] [/I]`) and ends with `[/I]`. Some strings are failing such as `aaaaa` and others like `aaa aa` are found! Maybe there is a better way to create such an html parser?
Thank you!

Edit: Ok, I found the solution, but I can't understand why this doesn't work!
The solution was `$pattern='#\[i\](.*?)\[/i\]#is'` but whats the difference?

Edit 2: Raider was correct the main problem was in `([^\[.)+]`. This will create the language `[I](a)^2n[/I]` so it will match `[I]aa[/I]`, but not `[I]aaaaa[/I]`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your subpattern `([^\[].)+` is the problem. Try `([^\[]+)`

Comment: hm... you are correct i created accidentally the lanquage [I](aa)^n[/I] !

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like this:

```
$parsed_str = '[I]Item1[/I].....html....[I]Item2[/I].....';
preg_match_all('~\[I\]([^\[.]+?)\[\/I\]~i', $parsed_str, $result);
print_r($result[1]);
```

The same results is given by:

```
preg_match_all('~\[I\]([^\[].+?)\[\/I\]~i', $parsed_str, $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is in line

```
$temp=$i[0];
```

Index 0 contains the entire matched pattern.  Instead you need to use index 1 - the first parenthesised part of the regexp:

```
$temp = $i[1]
```